# Manipulate the Object as result of DOM parser function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, domparser

Im gonna rebuild my answer because the first time was a i mess;

im trying to do two things first one is to get the body from a html
with dom parse;

```js
const stripHtml = function (html) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
    return doc.body.textContent || '';
};

const main_body = document.body;
console.log(stripHtml(main_body);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id="all">
    <script src="2-2.js"></script>
 <h1>1</h1>
 <div>
 <h2>1</h2>
 </div>
 <h2>2</h2>
 <h1>2</h1>
 <h2>base</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The DOMParser works fine when i use variables with strings like;

```html
"<div><p>Text here</p></div>"
```

my issue is here is that when i tried to use DOMParser with variables to select certain parts of the html document im getting "[object HTMLBodyElement]"

and dont know how to transform this object to String to able to use replace() function to strip tags and later to append to a element the result of the replace function.

This is the result html that i need for clarification, and my apologies for the conffusion.

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>1</h1>
<div>
  <h2>1</h2>
</div>
<h2>2</h2>
<h1>2</h1>
<h2>base</h2>
<pre>
1
1
2
2
base
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use the [`DOMParser` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), but you haven't provided enough detail to communicate your exact expectations.

Comment: sorry, i need to do without any api or jquery plain js, the idea is in the same html generate a new tag "pre" with the conversion to plain text from html.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963233/strip-tags-from-html-and-add-to-a-new-create-tag?noredirect=1#comment130597461_73963233) `DOMParser` is a native class. If you are in a JS environment with a DOM, then `DOMParser` is almost certainly there as well. The question is tagged with [tag:dom], so I'm guessing that's the case.

Comment: i see, sorry about that  im mostly new about dom manipulation and there a lot of things that i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Well i founded the solution, i was trying to complicate a lot of things, in the end was a way to get the text of the tags without needed to transform the elements simply as the follow code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const body = document.querySelector('body').innerText;

    const element = document.createElement('pre');

    const main_body = document.body;

    main_body.append(element)

    element.append(body)
});
```

This function get the text inside all the tags of body and wait for the DOM to load to execute the commands.